# Why can't I display the contents of an api in the console (getting 401 error)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, axios, http-status-code-401

I want to display the contents of this api in the console but it isn't working.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

error I'm getting:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
```

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Flights extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(response => {
                console.log("API Call ====> " + response);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}

export default Flights;
```

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}

Comment: @sjdm what do you mean by this?

Comment: My guess is that there needs to be some kind of access token or authentication token to be able to make the GET request

Comment: 401 Unauthorized - The request requires user authentication or, if the request included authorization credentials, authorization has been refused for those credentials. THIS IS FROM THE SPOTIFY DOCS

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/

Comment: You will need basic authentication and a token added to your request

Comment: Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `JSON.stringify()` method to parse the response content into a string before printing.

This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/m4nq5lrxxp

An alternative is directly printing it:

```
 axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);   // like this without string concatenation
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: oh ok, so it's not my code that's the problem but rather, the API is too secure to allow anybody to gain access to it.  Is that correct?

Comment: yep! it's not your code, it's about the API, you might follow their document in order to make it works. Details is here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow

Comment: Check my original post I changed it to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts ` and this time in the console I'm seeing `[object Object]` (It's not hitting the error).  Why can't I display it's content?

Comment: You could use JSON.stringify() to parse the response content into a string. This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/m4nq5lrxxp

Comment: `response.data` prints `[object Object]` repeatedly throughout the console.  `JSON.stringify()` prints the contents but in a very messy matter.

Comment: You are seeing `[object Object]` because you are concatenating the response with a string here: `console.log("API Call ====> " + response);` Either use this answer or use `console.log("API Call ====> ", response.data);` Do not add a `+` between `console.log` and your response.